# MSSQL - MSSMS v.18 - exec just one SQL-query by F5 shortcut in query window without selecting part of the query

Tags: sql-server

When I work with MSSQL database in SQL Server Management Studio v.18.1 (2021) it is handy to write some temporary select/insert/update or other kind of the sql-query in one Query window and when i need to execute one of them, i just select one sql-query and push F5, but that is tedious all the time select some sql-query.
How to execute just one sql-query by F5 at which my cursor is located now?

sample - i have Query window in MSSMS that contains two queries:

--first query
select * from table1

--second query
insert into table2
values(1,2)

If I press F5 - they will executed both, if i select text one of them and press F5 - executed just selected part of the queries.

Is there any way to split these two queries in one query window, and execute just one by F5 where my cursor is positioned now?

Comment: Without semicolons to separate the queries, a client tool will have to use heuristics to decide where one query ends and another starts. SSMS is a bit ... dated and doesn't do that. There are SSMS extensions or other tools that do a better job. One of the answers to the duplicate mentions SSMS Executor which supports all SSMS versions

Comment: Microsoft is pushing Azure Data Studio as the preferred, cross-platform management client. Azure Data Studio for example *does* have a `Run Current Query` command, whose shortcut is Ctrl+F5. Its schema comparison and code generation wizards are smarter than SSMS too.